# Amazon - узнать конфигурацию сервера через shell

Tags: linux, shell, amazon

Какими командами можно узнать информацию о задействованных CPU и RAM на сервере Amazon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cpu:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

ram:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
```

Answer (score 1):

Для CPU это утилиты **top**, **htop** и **mpstat**:

```
$ top
$ sudo apt-get install htop
$ htop
$ sudo apt-get install sysstat
$ mpstat -P ALL
```

Для RAM это:

```
$ free
$ cat /proc/meminfo
```